# Android emulator 15 and xubuntu 11.10 : can't switch to landscape mode

Tags: android-emulator, xubuntu

I've downloaded Android 15 on my Xubuntu 11.10 (64 bits) laptop. But though Fn and numeric keys are functionning in the host system, i can't manage to make the emulator switching to landscape mode :

- neither with Ctrl+F11, nor with NumPad 7
- neither with Ctrl+F12 nor with numPad 9

I've tried when I disable numLock, it does not change anything.

If I can use terminal to do it or change keys mapping from a file, i'm ready.

My keyboard configuation is Generic PC 105 keys, and french layout.

Thanks in advance for helps.

Comment: For the moment, the only I managed is to use the virtual keyboard of Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

num 7 on keypad. Only works only when numlock is off.

Comment: You have not read all my post (I've also tried by disabling numpad). Anyway, the problem seemed to come from my laptop keyboard, and I've bought a little usb keyboard, so the problem is solved.

Comment: My bad. You can ignore my answer.